# change the from mailid in centos 6.5 using sendmail

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, centos6.5

Sending a message from the Unix command line using mail TO_ADDR results in an email from $USER@$HOSTNAME. Is there a way to change the "From:" address inserted by mail?

For the record, I'm using centos 6.5 even i followed below this
    `mail -s "Subject" to@address.com -- -f from@address.com < body`

after i got this message

```
From: root <root@hostname.localdomain> 
To: -t@hostname.localdomain, -Fto@address.com,--@hostname.localdomain, from@address.com 
Subject: Subject
```

Comment: Just i got solution for this 
echo "email body" | mail -s "Subject here" -r from_email_address email_address_to

Comment: but it sent to spam instead of inbox